# This error message in Django means "TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This error message in Django means "TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable". This doesn't make sense!
This is my serializers:

```
class MatriculaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MATRICULA
        fields = (
            'ID_MATRICULA',
            'ID_USUARIO',
            'ID_TIPO_MATRICULA',
            'VALIDADE',
            'EXPEDICAO',
            'ISATIVO'
        )
```

this is my models

```
class MATRICULA(BASE):
    ID_MATRICULA = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    ID_USUARIO = models.ForeignKey(USUARIO, related_name='MATRICULA_ID_USUARIO',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    ID_TIPO_MATRICULA = models.ForeignKey(TIPO_MATRICULA, related_name='MATRICULA_TIPO_MATRICULA',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    VALIDADE = models.DateField
    EXPEDICAO = models.DateField(null=False)
    def __str__(self):
         str = (f"{self.ID_MATRICULA}")
         return str
```

this is my views

```
class MatriculaAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.MATRICULA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MatriculaSerializer
```

And this is my urls

```
path('matricula/', views.MatriculaAPIView.as_view(), name='matricula')
```

This error only happens with this model "Matricula" I have several others that work well, and they have the same type of coding.

Comment: The VALIDADE field on your model is not defined correctly, you need to pass an instance of a model field not the field class - `VALIDADE = models.DateField()`

Comment: I achieved! It was actually a very simple problem, but unfortunately the output from the terminal didn't help me find it: In the models "Matricula" the field "Validade" did not contain a "( )" and therefore it was not calling the method the way it was to be called.